# ASP.NET core 2.2: attribute routing issue

Tags: asp.net-core

Trying to understand why one of the controller action routes defined in the attribute is considered as invalid.

When i define the action route {id}/image application throws an exception on startup.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternException: There is an incomplete parameter in the route template. Check that each '{' character has a matching '}' character.

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class WishlistController : ControllerBase
    {
        //works fine
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        //action...

        //throws error on startup
        [HttpGet("{id}/image}")]
        //action...
    }
```

I want to have a route that will look like api/wishlist/{id}/image

Comment: Just for completeness, what do the action methods look like?

Comment: You've got `image}` instead of `image`. Remove that erroneous `}` and it should be fine.

Comment: Ahhh, that was quick :D I've checked the routes multiple times but didn't noticed it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the error you are getting, this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/image}")]
```

Produces the following error:

> Check that each '{' character has a matching '}' character.

If you inspect closely, you will notice that the `image}` part of your route has a closing bracket, but it's missing it's corresponding opening one (I'm assuming you were trying to type something along the lines of `{image}`).

You actually don't need the brackets there at all. Change it to:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/image")]
```